# expo-store-review not working when StoreReview.requestReview()

Tags: react-native, expo

I am runing the following function to request User review. My app.json has the appstoreUrl and playstore one, I don't know why the function `StoreReview.requestReview()` is returning `undefined` and of course not showing any modal. This is my function for requesting a review

```
const handleReview = async () => {
  StoreReview.hasAction().then((hasAction) => {
    if (hasAction) {
      StoreReview.requestReview().then((res) => {
        console.log('Response is...', res)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    } else {
      const reviewUrl = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? Constants.manifest.extra.ios_review_url : Constants.manifest.extra.android_review_url;
      Linking.openURL(reviewUrl);
    }
  })
}
```

Does it matter if I already did a review? Please bare in mind that here I am trying to work with Expo without going into a managed workflow

Comment: how or from where did you get your appstoreUrl and playstore url? @Rocio

Comment: @vana22 from the web, if your app is published you can search it on the internet and you get a playstore/appstore url (its usually the typical url plus an ID for your app)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it matters that you have already done a review.  StoreReview is a wrapper around the App Store and Play Store APIs.  Both of these use their own internal logic to decide when to present the review prompt to the user, and both of them will not show the prompt if the user has already left a review.

By design, neither API returns a result to the app developer indicating whether they have left a review or what rating they may have given.  This is to prevent abuse by app developers.

In order to see the review prompt again, you should delete the review for the user.  There are other guidelines as well; both platforms limit the number of times the user has seen the review prompt in different ways (# of times per app version, per year, etc).

See:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#troubleshooting ('Issue: The user has already reviewed the app.')
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Its super useful to understand the issue. Do you know why the object might be returning undefined?

Comment: By design, neither API returns a result to the app developer indicating whether they have left a review or what rating they may have given. This is to prevent abuse by app developers.

Comment: I have a question. If I run StoreReview.requestReview() in my app and the user selects "Not now" will it keep asking them or will it know that they answered that and never ask them again?

Comment: @Cole check the docs - both platforms limit the number of times the user has seen the review prompt in different ways (# of times per app version, per year, etc)